# How do I get started learning COBOL and which compiler should I use?

Tags: open-source, software-development, programming, cobol

I'm interested in learning COBOL, but I'm absolutely lost, the only learning resource seems to be from IBM but their compiler is paid and seems to be more towards mainframes and z/OS, and the only free COBOL compiler seems to be gnuCOBOL but I'm afraid of it being unmaintained, not having all features of the language.

I know it's a really old language, but I really wanted to try writing some personal projects with it.

Comment: No idea about quality / completeness etc. but maybe a starting point https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnucobol/

Comment: @albert I found out that visual cobol personal edition is free for a year, I'm wondering if that would be a good alternative to gnuCOBOL as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

> the only free COBOL compiler seems to be GnuCOBOL but I'm afraid of it being unmaintained ...

Hm, let's have a look... first release 2002 as OpenCOBOL and since then... regular releases and more regular testing snapshots. So nothing to be afraid of.

> ... not having all features of the language.

Actually there is not a single COBOL implementation that supports all of COBOL 2002+; most implementations claim full ANSI85 support with selected COBOL 2002+ features (and while this claim *could* be backed up by running the *full* NIST85 testsuite, I'm not sure how much implementations would pass it).

From ANSI85 the only thing missing is support of the obsolete COMMUNICATION SECTION (which is the reason GnuCOBOL disabled this specific part of NIST85 testuite; a feature that was dropped with COBOL2002 and I'm not aware of a current implementation that supports it).
The main part (currently and likely for at least one year) missing in GnuCOBOL from COBOL 2002+ is object orientated COBOL, something that is used "in the wild" *sometimes* (often as an implementor-specific extension to ANSI85 in a not-fully-compatible way to COBOL2002+), as there are many environments where this is not used.

As GnuCOBOL also supports a lot of extensions from different COBOL implementations you are very likely good (or even best) to go with it, *at least* for the beginning (keeping in mind that GnuCOBOL is used in production also in government and banking environments and even in some academic high-performance environment, according to the GnuCOBOL "FAQ").

For learning COBOL you possibly want to check out:

- [Worldcities Tutorial](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnucobol/contrib/HEAD/tree/trunk/samples/worldcities/)
- [COBOL Programming Course](https://github.com/openmainframeproject/cobol-programming-course) from the Open Mainframe Project (compiling with `gcc -std=ibm-strict` instead of JCL)